# Compilation Error with no visible errors in Eclipse

Tags: jsp, struts-1, taglib

Eclipse isn't showing any errors for my jsp. Yet when I try to access it in Tomcat, I get this error:

```
Oct 24, 2013 4:27:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

at  org.apache.jsp.jvn_005fjsp.Findings.jvnFindingsContent_jsp._jspService(jvnFindingsContent_jsp.java:144)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:624)
at org.apache.struts.taglib.template.GetTag.doStartTag(GetTag.java:201)
at org.apache.jsp.inc.JVNTemplates.SpecialUI.DarkGUICancelPO_jsp._jspx_meth_template_005fget_005f3(DarkGUICancelPO_jsp.java:273)
at org.apache.jsp.inc.JVNTemplates.SpecialUI.DarkGUICancelPO_jsp._jspService(DarkGUICancelPO_jsp.java:170)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:624)
at org.apache.struts.taglib.template.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:158)
at org.apache.jsp.jvn_005fjsp.Findings.jvnFindings_jsp._jspService(jvnFindings_jsp.java:155)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.estenda.security.TrustedAuthenticationServletFilter.doFilter(TrustedAuthenticationServletFilter.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.estenda.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:39)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
at org.apache.struts.taglib.template.GetTag.doStartTag(GetTag.java:207)
```

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
at org.apache.struts.taglib.template.GetTag.doStartTag(GetTag.java:207)
at org.apache.jsp.inc.JVNTemplates.SpecialUI.DarkGUICancelPO_jsp._jspx_meth_template_005fget_005f3(DarkGUICancelPO_jsp.java:273)
at org.apache.jsp.inc.JVNTemplates.SpecialUI.DarkGUICancelPO_jsp._jspService(DarkGUICancelPO_jsp.java:170)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:624)
at org.apache.struts.taglib.template.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:158)
at org.apache.jsp.jvn_005fjsp.Findings.jvnFindings_jsp._jspService(jvnFindings_jsp.java:155)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.estenda.security.TrustedAuthenticationServletFilter.doFilter(TrustedAuthenticationServletFilter.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.estenda.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:39)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Can anyone suggest other tools for looking for JSP compilation errors?

Comment: Is that the complete stack trace? What versions of everything are you deploying?

Comment: Tomcat 6, Struts 1.2.7, Java 1.6, Eclipse Kepler

Comment: You were right, I had more to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new, temporary Java project in Eclipse. Look in Tomcat's work directory for the file with compilation problem (looks to be jvnFindingsContent_jsp.java) and add it to your project. You'll also need to add some of the Tomcat libraries to resolve a number of unknown imports. I'd just add all of them - it will be quicker. Then you'll need to get Eclipse to move the file to the correct package and at that point you should have a java file that Eclipse can try and compile. You should then be able to see what Eclipse is having trouble compiling and hopefully that will map back to a now obvious error in the JSP.

Depending on the structure of the JSP you may need to add some other java files to the project such as those generated for tag files.

Comment: how will I know what eclipse is having trouble compiling?

Comment: Eclipse will mark up the Java file with the compilation error just like any other Java file.

Comment: Apparently, it was an error in the JSP Eclipse wasn't picking up:
       T_ID%>');"id=  vs T_ID%>');" id=
The space between the tags was an error.

Comment: A co-worker was using Tomcat 7 and got this error: “The JSP specification requires that an attribute name is preceded by whitespace.”

Answer (score 1):

Enable JSP Syntax and Content Validators in Eclipse perhaps?

Eclipse->Window->Preferences->Validation; verify that build or optionally manual are checked.